# Oracle Shrink space issue- alter table <table> shrink space returns the error ORA-10631because of function based indexes. Any workaround exists?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have deleted some data from the table TAB1. 
In order to claim the space i am performing

alter table TAB1 enable row movement;  > goes fine
alter table TAB1 shrink space;   > ORA-10631: SHRINK clause should not be specified for this object

This is because there are function based indexes in the table. We can't shrink a table with function based indexes. Any work around exists for this issue.

Comment: have you tried moving the table? Alter table T tablespace X. I've never tried that when an FBI is invovled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping the Index was the most likely alternative:

1. Drop the Index
2. Shrink the table space
3. Create the same index.

Comment: According to Oracle 11g [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2192484): _Segment shrink is not supported for tables with function-based indexes, domain indexes, or bitmap join indexes._

Answer (score 0):

Seems unlikely, other than dropping the FBI and then re-creating it.